# When is an infinite product of natural numbers regularizable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, divergent-series, products, regularization

I only recently heard about the concept of [$\zeta$-regularization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zeta-RegularizedProduct.html), which allows the evaluation of things like

$$\infty != \prod_{k=1}^\infty k = \sqrt{2\pi}$$

and

$$\infty \# = \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k = 4\pi^2$$

where $n\#$ is a [primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html), and $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime. (The expression for the infinite product of primes is proven [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-007-0350-z).) That got me wondering if, given a sequence of positive integers $m_k$ (e.g. the Fibonacci numbers or the central binomial coefficients), it is always possible to evaluate the infinite product

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty m_k$$

in the $\zeta$-regularized sense. It would seem that this would require studying the convergence and the possibility of analytically continuing the corresponding Dirichlet series, but I am not too well-versed at these things. If such a regularization is not always possible, what restrictions should be imposed on the $m_k$ for a regularized product to exist?

I'd love to read up on references for this subject. Thank you!

Comment: How did you get $\prod k =\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: @Fabian, if $\zeta^\prime(s)=-\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\log\,k}{k^s}$, then consider $\exp(-\zeta^\prime(0))$...

Comment: a free online preprint about the second equation is at http://cds.cern.ch/record/630829 (2013-05-13)

Comment: I don't know if it helps or if it is obvious, but via exponentiation the problem is exactly the same as a classic series.

Comment: It seems to me that a physical interpretation of regularization would be to "measure" an object as it passes through the entrance to a black hole at a velocity asymptotically approaching the speed of light.

Comment: @TimmyTurner It very much bothers me that $(-1/2)!=\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{2\pi}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{-1/2}1=-1/2$.  I almost feel like some divergent series have a strange "plug in -1/2" type of nature.  Think it is question worthy?

Comment: It looks like an analog of Ramanujan summation to me: $\infty!=\Pi_{k=1}^\infty k=\exp\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty\log k$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325169/zeta-regulated-product-solving-without-the-zeta-function?rq=1 My own shot about the subject without any background knowlegde cause i was just as curious. I know i should add some constrains for the methode.

Comment: To me, this looks wrong: definitely, $\operatorname{reg}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln k=\ln \sqrt{2\pi}$. But exponent of regularized value is not the same as regularized value of exponent!

Answer (score 5):

Given an increasing sequence $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\lambda_3<\ldots$ one defines the regularized infinite product
$$
\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}\lambda_n=\exp\left(-\zeta'_{\lambda}(0)\right),
$$
where $\zeta_{\lambda}$ is the zeta function associated to the sequence $(\lambda_n)$,
$$
\zeta_{\lambda}(s)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\lambda_n^{-s}.
$$
(See the paper: E.Munoz Garcia and R.Perez-Marco."The Product over all Primes is $4\pi^2$". http://cds.cern.ch/record/630829/files/sis-2003-264.pdf )

In the paper( https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0903/0903.4883.pdf ) I have evaluated the
$$
\prod_{p-primes}p^{\log p}=\prod_{p-primes}e^{\log^2p}=\exp\left(24\zeta''(0)+12\log^2(2\pi)\right)
$$
where $\zeta''(0)$ is the second derivative of Riemann's Zeta function in $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim that $\operatorname{reg} \prod_{k=1}^\infty k = \sqrt{2\pi}$ looks misleading and wrong to me.

Definitely, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty k=\exp \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln k$.

Also, definitely $\operatorname{reg}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln k=\ln \sqrt{2\pi}$

But exponent of the regularized value is not the same as the regularized value of exponent!

More honestly, the value $\sqrt{2\pi}$ corresponds not to the regularized (finite) value of the product, but to its [**hypermodulus** as defined here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470644/what-are-the-properties-of-this-new-characteristic-of-mathematical-objects). Hypermodulus is the exponent of the scalar finite part of the logarithm of the object.