# Is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty P_{2n-1}$ regularizable?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product, regularization

Assume that $P_n$ denotes the $n$'th prime for this entire question.

**Inspriation:** I was dumbfounded by the fact that: $$\hat\prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty P_{n}=4\pi^2$$ 
After further investigation, I learned of many other properties of zeta-regulation, as well as their proofs (to a reasonable extent). I realized nothing had been done of this question: $$2*5*11\cdots=\hat\prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty P_{2n-1}=\kappa$$
and solve for $\kappa$.

**Issues:** I am fairly competent in the usage of zeta-regularization, but am lost here, because it seems that zeta regularization doesn't work with $2n-1$ used instead of $n$. Unfortunately, I couldn't really figure out how to apply that on to this here. I was driven, from Resource 1, that a *potential* to use bounds was created, but my inability to logically understand this problem made it impossible to determine if $4\pi^2$ or $\sqrt{2\pi}$ would be upper or lower.

**Questions:**

a) Can $\kappa$ be zeta-regularized?

b) If it can, could you please assist me in a calculation of $\kappa$?

**Side notes:** I have had this question on my mind almost forever, and would really love an answer. Although I would most appreciate a proof, really anything will help me here. I am also somewhat uncertain with my tag choices, so please consider editing before immediately downvoting. The following were helpful in the construction of this problem.

1) [When is an infinite product of natural numbers regularizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177946/when-is-an-infinite-product-of-natural-numbers-regularizable)

2) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zeta-RegularizedProduct.html

(I realize the former has been unanswered, but the problem had helpful comments as well as the idea to find a bound. )

Comment: Rather that asking this here (and lose reputation points through the bounty process), you should probably have asked it on MathOverflow.

Comment: @OrangeJuliusCesaer Didn't you already bounty another question of mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a set of indices $K\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we can define the generalized prime zeta function
$$
{\cal P}_{K}(s)=\sum_{k\in K}\frac{1}{p_k^s},
$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.  Following the thread of the proof that $\prod p = 4\pi^2$, we note that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{{\cal P}_K (s)} &=& \prod_{k\in K}\exp\left(p_k^{-s}\right)
\\ &=& \prod_{k \in K} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - p_k^{-ns}\right)^{-\mu(n)/n} 
\\ &=& \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k \in K} \left(1 - p_k^{-ns}\right)^{-\mu(n)/n}
\\ &=& \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta_K(ns)^{\mu(n)/n},
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Moebius function, and $\zeta_K$ is a suitably generalized Riemann zeta function: $\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{m}m^{-s}$, where the sum is over natural numbers $m$ all of whose prime factors are in $\{ p_{k\in K} \}$.  Unless $K$ is a finite set, this series definition for $\zeta_K(s)$ converges only for $\Re(s)>1$; it needs to be defined by analytic continuation elsewhere.  The logarithmic derivative is
$$
{\cal P}^{\prime}_{K}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\frac{n\zeta^{\prime}_K(ns)}{\zeta_K(ns)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\frac{\zeta^{\prime}_K(ns)}{\zeta_K(ns)},
$$
and so
$$
{\cal P}^{\prime}_{K}(0) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\right)\frac{\zeta^{\prime}_K(0)}{\zeta_K(0)}=\frac{1}{\zeta(0)}\frac{\zeta^{\prime}_K(0)}{\zeta_K(0)}=-2\frac{\zeta^{\prime}_K(0)}{\zeta_K(0)}.$$
We conclude that
$$
\prod_{k\in K}p_k=\exp\left(-{\cal P}^{\prime}_K(0)\right)=\exp\left(2\frac{\zeta^{\prime}_K(0)}{\zeta_K(0)}\right).
$$
This puts your original question in terms of a hopefully easier-to-answer result, which depends only on the analytic continuation of a particular infinite sum.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't choose to vote here, just to let you know. However, I was a bit confused at where $P_{2k}$ comes in. Also, I probably would have given you the bounty if you had finished it.

Comment: OP's question corresponds to $K=\{1,3,5,\ldots\}$, or $\{p_{k\in K}\} = \{2,5,11,17,\ldots\}$.

Comment: I just understood what you did here. I'm sorry for not giving you the other bounty. I'll see what OJC says though